# don't work onClick in buttons at list_view height = match_parent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview

I think because my `ListView` is set to `layout_height="match_parent"`, the `Buttons` are not called `onClick` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        Log.d(TAG_DEBUG,"0");
    } else{
        Button button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG_DEBUG, "TEST");
            }
        });
    }
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/num_ord"
        android:background="@drawable/fon_ord"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/title_ord"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|italic"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Sum:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/fon_ord"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/sum_ord"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Col:"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/fon_ord"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/count_ord"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="106dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="DD:"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/fon_ord"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/date_ord"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="Del"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="Ed"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="-37dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_orders"
        android:focusable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I press the buttons, nothing happens, why?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you can, try to save in a variable the return of super.getView and use it instead of convertView

Comment: I don't understand your title: your `ListView` has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, not `match_parent`..!

Comment: 1) I can't see that your layout corresponds to what you've shown on the picture. 2) Looks like you're trying to get button1 from adapter's getView() method, although button1 is out of the listview's item (unless you have the same names for two buttons).